# Transparency issues Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have strange issue regarding the use of transparency in Android.

I have a gradient which goes from orange to transparent. This works fine on the Nexus 5 I have been using.

However I ran the app on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and there is a strange result.

Heres an example...

NEXUS 5 (CORRECT)
[image]

SAMSUNG GALAXY S3 (WRONG)
[image]

Heres the XML background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <gradient android:endColor="@android:color/transparent" android:gradientRadius="100" android:startColor="#ffd060" android:type="radial" />

        <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#ffd060" />

        <corners android:radius="200dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#D1D1D1" />

        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this problem? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Yeah same here (over a year later!), from what I can tell older samsung devices don't handle transparency gradients at all which is a shame. Not sure what a decent solution is though.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the gradient `endColor` by `startColor` **with transparency**.

```
<gradient android:endColor="#00ffd060" android:gradientRadius="100" android:startColor="#ffd060" android:type="radial"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the stroke for? Try removing this line:

```
<stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#D1D1D1" />
```